# Typing an object literal's shorthand method

Tags: typescript

If I have an async function type definition like

```js
type MyAsyncFunctionType = (arg:string) => Promise<string>
```

how could I use it to type an async function I have defined on an object literal using the [ES2015 object method shortand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)?

```js
const myObject = {
  async myFunction(arg) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little gnarly and you may want to extract it into a named type, but you can type it like so:

```
type MyAsyncFunctionType = (arg: string) => Promise<string>

const myObject: { myFunction: MyAsyncFunctionType } = {
    async myFunction(arg) {
        // ... code here
    }
}
```